# How to start applications on a remote second machine with systemd

Tags: linux, systemd, remote

The question is: can `systemd` start a service on a second remote machine?

Scenario:

applications 3X the name I call it app1 app2 app3
machines 2X the name I call it ms1 and ms2

```
----MS1---------MS2
----app1--------app3
----app2------------
```

I create a service like:

app.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Application
[Service]
# The dummy program will exit
Type=oneshot
# Execute a dummy program
ExecStart=/bin/true
# This service shall be considered active after start
RemainAfterExit=yes
[Install]
# Components of this application should be started at boot time
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

app1.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Application Component 1
# When systemd stops or restarts the app.service, the action is propagated to this unit
PartOf=app.service
# Start this unit after the app.service start
After=app.service
[Service]
# Pretend that the component is running
ExecStart=/bin/sleep infinity
# Restart the service on non-zero exit code when terminated by a signal other than SIGHUP, SIGINT, SIGTERM or SIGPIPE
Restart=on-failure
[Install]
# This unit should start when app.service is starting
WantedBy=app.service
```

app2.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Application Component 2
PartOf=app.service
After=app.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sleep infinity
Restart=on-failure
[Install]
WantedBy=app.service
```

app3.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Application Component 3
PartOf=app.service
After=app.service
# This unit should start after the app-component2 started
After=app-component2.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sleep infinity
Restart=on-failure
[Install]
WantedBy=app.service
```

What can I do to init `app3.service` on the second machine? Is it feasible with `systemd` or need it a script?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html-single/system_administrators_guide/index#sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Remote (updated link) you can actually do this, but I have never tried that. It's ssh based and I don't know how to use it in file :(, but your `app3.service` might execute something like `ssh -i /path/to/ssh_key user@host systemctl start real_service`.

Comment: The link to RedHat's documentation now returns 404 :-(

Comment: @MikhailT. I updated link.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. Now, is there a way to express dependency on a _remote_ service inside my own `.service` file? Something like: `After: mysqld.service@remote-server`?

Answer (score 0):

I achieve this by using a local service which launches `netcat` to trigger the remote service to start via socket.

`local.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Local control of a remote service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/nc remote-machine remote-port
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal
SuccessExitStatus=1
```

`remote.socket`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Socket for allowing remote control of our service

[Socket]
ListenStream=listen-port
Accept=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

`remote@.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=A service running on another machine
Requires=remote.socket

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/path/to/application
StandardInput=socket
StandardOutput=socket
StandardError=socket
```

Install `local.service` on your primary machine.  Install `remote.socket` and `remote@.service` on the machine you are offloading this work to.  On the remote machine start listening with

```
systemctl start remote.socket
```

Test this out on your local machine (substitute `remote-ip` and `remote-port`):

```
netcat remote-machine-ip  remote-port
```

You should see your remote process run.  `stdout` and `stderr` should be appearing in your terminal.  If the application accepts `stdin`, you can also use that here.
Kill `netcat` locally and you should see the remote service stop.  Once your happy with that, enable the socket to it starts listening after bootup by running this on the remote machine:

```
systemctl enable remote.socket
```

Finally, put it all togeather with

```
systemctl start local.sevice
```

Your remote service should be running

```
systemctl stop local.servce
```

Your remote service should stop.

Now you can add any `Requires=` `WantedBy=` `PartOf=` relationships you want to `local.service` to trigger the remote service.